# How to redirect back with error message in middleware?

Tags: laravel

I want redirect back with error message in custom middleware of else condition in laravel 10

I have tried laravel redirect which is throwing error like site cant be reached

Below is my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Models\Roles;
use App\Models\Users;
use App\Http\Controllers\Helpers\CheckIfUserExist;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

// use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class CheckUserRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        // MessageBag $message_bag;
        if (Auth::check()) {
        $roleName = ltrim($role, ':');
        $authUser = Auth::user();
        if($authUser){
            $user = $authUser->getAttributes();
            $role_id = $user['role_id'];
            $role = Roles::where('id', $role_id)->first();
            $role_name = $role->name;
        // if ($user->role->name === $roleName) {
            if ($roleName === $role_name) {
                // Allow access for the specific user
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                // return back()->withSuccess("The data has been updated");
                 // Redirect to a specific route if the conditions are not met
                // return Redirect::back(); // Create this route
                // return Redirect::to('/employer/login');
                // return redirect()->intended('/employer');

                // Redirect back with a message indicating that the credentials do not match
                // return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Credentials do not match.');
            }

        }
    }
        return $next($request);
        // return redirect('/'); // Redirect to the homepage or another appropriate route
    }

}
```

Kindly suggest me anyone how to achieve that

Comment: ``redirect()->back()`` should work fine, can you attach the error you get while using it? try ``back()->with()`` if you haven't.

Comment: Redirecting back would cause an infinite loop of redirects as Laravel has no means to figure out where `back()` is in that context. Validation errors should not be handled in Middleware.